# Not able to register device and send message on gcm

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android app which sends `gcm` message to `phonebook contacts`. I am creating registration method in `asp.net C#`. When I am registering my device I am getting error at server side that is :

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Error=InvalidRegistration</string>
```

Is it necessary to have `google play account` to send `gcm` message?

Comment: You need to register your app in the Google API Console.

Comment: Go through GCM document first to get detailed understanding about GCM working - https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Ok. Thank you @user13